# how to refer to main xaml from another class

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to update textblock1 to 'there' from a class other than the main.  As shown this code gives no errors, but does not work.  Textblock1 is set to
FieldModifier="Public".

```
namespace myProgram
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        Library stuff = new Library();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void mainStuff()
        {
            stuff.Doit(new MainPage());
        }
    }
}
namespace myProgram
{
    public class Library
    {
        public void Doit(MainPage mainPage)
        {
            mainPage.textblock1.Text = "there";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you using MVVM ?

Comment: This is a UWP project...  I want to separate the large main body of code into smaller pieces...  I have not used MVVM...

Comment: I updated the problem to show complete syntax.  The suggested solutions are not working.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass it a `new MainPage()` ?

Comment: I can't figure the syntax to pass the page itself.

Comment: I was unnecessarily taking on housekeeping tasks.  I split unwieldy code into partial classes.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

### The short answer

Pass your `Window` as a parameter to the other class.

```
public class Library {

    public void Doit(MainPage mainPage)
    {
         mainPage.textblock1.Text = "there";
    }
}
```

**EDIT** According to the other answer that is posted here, you can't (by default) access controls from outside the class (as they are set to `protected`).
You can override the access modifier to `public` (refer to the other answer), but that seems to violate the idea that UI and data logic should be separated.

It does work, from a technical point of view; I just suggest not doing it because it can lead to future problems in development.

### The cautionary answer

You should endeavour to keep your UI and data logic separate. In most cases where you want another class to access your window's controls; you are violating the principle of UI and data logic segregation.

In short, you don't want **anyone** (except `MainPage`) to be aware that a `Mainpage` has a `Textblock`; let alone giving them the ability to set its content directly.

In `MainPage`, create a public property:

```
public String MyDisplayValue
{
    get
    {
        return this.textblock1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.textblock1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

In your external `Library` class:

```
public void Doit(MainPage mainPage)
{
     mainPage.MyDisplayValue = "there";
}
```

Functionally speaking, the application works the same as in the short answer I supplied. But this one creates a better separation between UI and data logic.

This is a matter of good practice, not technical requirement.

Comment: I would need a MyDisplayValue routine for every variable I need to change in a large project.  I would like to go with your first solution.  That way I do not have to fool with the XAML, and changing the references to a large number of variables would be easier.

Comment: @pollaris: Do please check the other answer too; since I'm not sure if you need to explicitly mark these fields as public or not. Although I do think that your decision to make window controls publically available is a minefield. _Especially for a large code base (which you are faced with)_, decisions like these can very quickly spiral out of control. I highly advise against having multiple sources (classes) all have direct access to a single window's controls. It's probably going to end up conflicting down the line.

Comment: I want to do this in a proper and preferred way.  Are you recommending the FieldModifier approach?  I have no experience with MVVM - is that a solution to chopping a large program up into smaller pieces?

Comment: @pollaris I highly suggest having the access to your window controls strictly regulated through the use of custom made properties and methods (= my cautionary answer). If you don't want to create a property for each existing control, you can still make a larger public method in `MainPage`, e.g. `public void SetALotOfValues(string valueOne, int valueTwo, string valueThree)` and then have that method put each value into the appropriate window control. That way, you retain the segragation of UI/data, while still making it possible to publically set the controls' content.

Comment: @pollaris: A lot of this hinges on how good you want to make it. MVVM is considerably better than my suggestion, but it might also take a considerable amount of extra effort; since you are dealing with an existing code base that needs to be refactored. You might get a more in-depth answer on CodeReview.SE; as this is mainly concerned with refactoring (without going overboard) rather than a technical problem or error.

Comment: I updated the problem to reflect more exactly what I need.  I cannot get passing the window to work.  Could you provide a more complete example, and please do not use mainPage as a variable name...:)

Comment: @pollaris: The question seems unchanged. What's new? `public mainStuff() {}` is not valid code, as the method name is not that of the containing class; and only constructors omit the return type. Why did passing the window not work? Any errors you're getting? Did you observe the other posted answer that mentions you have to specifically make those controls publically accessible? What's wrong with using `mainPage` as a variable name? Not that I can't change it, I'm just puzzled as to why it matters in an **example**. If you're blindly copying code, I would advise against that.

Answer (score 1):

Make you TextBlock control public like this.    `x:FieldModifier="public"`

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlockName"
           x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

Then expose you MainPage class

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page 
{  
    public static MainPage mainPage { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mainPage = this;       
    }
}
```

then in our `Library` class do this:

```
public class Library
    {
        private TextBlock myTb{ get; set; }
        public Library()
        {
            myTb = MainPage.mainPage.TextBlockName;
        }
        public void Doit()
        {
            myTb.Text = "there";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I thought of using FieldModifier.  I will do it this way if I have to.  Is there a way I can do this without modifying the XAML?  I have many variables I need to change...

Comment: @pollaris then you should consider using some MVVM framework

Comment: @ravikumar: If OP's concern is the complexity of having to refactor a large, badly written code base; then the implementation of a new framework isn't going to make it any easier (for the refactoring itself, that is).